# I have a pytorch image classifier training, and I want to pause training and save the weights at time of program pause. Can I do this?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm in the middle of training a classifier that's been training for a few days now, but my problem is that I  didn't code in to save .pt checkpoints throughout training, and so I'll only end up with a weights file when the program is done with all of its epochs. Is there a way to pause training (PAUSE BREAK) and save the model's weights right now?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, no.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, PyTorch does not have a native API for this at the moment.
For the current job, you could use an IDE like [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org) or [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) to attach a debugger to the running process and set a break point somewhere in your code and extract the weights and biases.

For future jobs, you could always create checkpoints inside the epochs loop and save the learned model there. [This](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/saving-and-loading-a-model-in-pytorch/2610/3) link will help.